# WPF How do I stop MaskedTextBox from clearing text when I click on it

Tags: c#, wpf

This is the xaml of my MaskedTextBox(from Extended WPF Toolkit) which I bind the text with property `Time` in my datacontext.

```
<wpfx:MaskedTextBox
    x:Name="MyMaskedTextBox"
    AllowPromptAsInput="True"
    Mask="00:00:00"
    PromptChar="0"
    ResetOnPrompt="False"
    Text="{Binding Time, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

This is the part of my Datacontext that updates it, and my `Time` property.

```
public class MyViewModel : ObservableObject, INavigationAware {
    public string Time { 
        get; 
        set; //break point 1
    } 
    public static void UpdateTime(string time) {
        Time = time;
        OnPropertyChanged("Time");
    }
}
```

The problem is whenever I click on the MaskedTextBox, the text reverts back to the prompt character.

For example I would start up the app and the MaskedTextBox would have 00:00:00. After some event, I update the time property to 12:34:56, and it would correctly show on the UI. But when I click on the MaskedTextBox, it changes the text back to 00:00:00.

Break point 1's call stack just shows "external code". I couldn't find an option in the document to turn this behavior off, how do I stop it?

Comment: Should MyViewModel Time raise NotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: @VictorChelaru thanks for the help, and yes it should, as I also want to reflect the changes from datacontext to the UI.

Comment: and it does raise it, because ObservableObject already handles it when I do ```OnPropertyChanged("Time");```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to bind the `Value` property to your `Time` property instead of binding the `Text` property:

```
<wpfx:MaskedTextBox
    ...
    Value="{Binding Time, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

The control itself sets the `Text` property based on the `Value` and the `Mask`.

Comment: thanks for the help, unfortunately I have switched from using MaskedTextBox to regular textbox and limit user input myself. the code has changed too much so I can't really verify this easily. I could not get this to work myself when I also tried this, but I have looked into the source code and this does seem to be the right solution, so it might just be my setup somewhere, but I'll still select this as the answer